# Calc I: Related Rate Problem

Tags: calculus

A kite $100$ ft. above the ground moves horizontally at a speed of $11$ ft/s. At what rate is the angle (in radians) between the string and the horizontal decreasing when $200$ ft. of string has been let out?

I've gotten this far
my triangle looks like this:

$x=$? $r=200$ $y=100$

$\frac{\mathrm{dx} }{\mathrm{d} r}=11$

$\frac{\mathrm{dx} }{\mathrm{d} r}=200sec^2\Theta   \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d\Theta} }{\mathrm{d} r}$

Comment: Is the rate supposed to be radians per second or radians per ft? Or does it not matter?

Comment: radians per second

Answer (score 1):

You have a right triangle with hypotenuse $r = 200$ ft and a leg $y = 100$ ft. This corresponds to a $30-60-90$ triangle, so $x = 100\sqrt{3}$ ft. Also, $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = 11$ ft/s.

Therefore, $\sin(\theta) = \frac{opp}{hyp} = \frac{100}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+10000\right)}}$. Using the Chain Rule,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \sin(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = \color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \sin(\theta) \cdot 11 = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta} \sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}} \tag{1}$$

The  blue part becomes

$$\color{purple}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \sin(\theta)} \cdot 11 = \cos(\theta) \cdot \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}$$

Now,

$$\color{purple}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \sin(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(\frac{100}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+10000\right)}}\right) = -\frac{100x}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+10000\right)^3}}} \tag{2}$$

By substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$, the only remaining variable is the unknown: $\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}$.

Note that $\cos(\theta)$ is simply found through the original right triangle and is $\frac{adj}{hyp} = \frac{x}{r} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal distance is increasing at a rate of $11$ ft/s, or $11t$ where $t$ is time in seconds. Hence
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{100}{11t} \implies \theta=\arctan\left(\frac{100}{11t}\right).$$
Take the derivative and we get
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{-1100}{121t^2+10000}.$$
Now all we need to do is solve for time. I assume at $t=0$ the kite is an a horizontal length of $x=0$. Using the Pythagorean Theorem we get
$$(11t)^2 + 100^2=200^2 \implies t=\frac{100\sqrt{3}}{11}.$$
Now evaluate our derivative at $t=\frac{100\sqrt{3}}{11}$ and our answer is
$$\left.\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right\vert_{t=\frac{100\sqrt{3}}{11}} = -\frac{11}{400}.$$
In other words, the angle was changing at a rate of $-\frac{11}{400}$ radians per second.

Answer (score 0):

[image]From the diagram, $\tan\theta = \frac hx$. 
Take the time derivatives of both sides,

$$\sec^2\theta \>\frac{d\theta}{dt} = -\frac{h}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

We also have $\sec\theta = \frac sx$ and plug it into above expression to evaluate the rate of decreasing angle,

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = -\frac{h}{s^2}\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{100}{200^2}\cdot 11=-\frac{11}{400}\>\text{rad/s}$$

Answer (score 0):

$x = 100\cot \theta\\
\frac {d\theta}{dt} = \frac {d\theta}{dx}\frac {dx}{dt}$

$\frac {d\theta}{dx} = \dfrac {1}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}\\
\frac {dx}{d\theta} = -100\csc^2 \theta, \frac {dx}{dt} = 11 \frac {ft}{sec}$

When the string is $200$ ft, $\csc\theta = 2$

$\frac {d\theta}{dt}=-\frac {11}{400}$